# Laravel Envoy with Laravel Sail problem - envoy not running

Tags: laravel, envoyproxy, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel Sail project, and I am trying to use Envoy to deploy. I followed the guidelines of the Laravel documentation, I installed Envoy, created the Envoy.blade.php file in the root, but when I try to call:

`sail envoy run envoy-task`

or:

`sail vendor/bin/envoy run envoy-task`

Docker compose options and commands are listed, and envoy does not start at all. Why is this happening?

I tried to find solution from everywhere, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly quick fix luckily, `sail` has a limited list of commands that it can run directly.

You can see what they are by looking inside `vendor/bin/sail` (it's a text file) or just running `./vendor/bin/sail` directly. Laravel have added many, such as `up`, `down`, `artisan`, `test`, `shell`, `composer`, `npm`, and so on.

If the command is not supported by `sail`, it will pipe it through to the `docker-compose` command.

In this case the `envoy` and `vendor/bin/envoy` commands you tried to run are not valid `docker-compose` commands, so instead it fails and shows you the full list of Docker Compose commands.

#### Workaround

Try this instead:

```
sail exec laravel.test php vendor/bin/envoy run envoy-task
```

This will `exec` (run/execute) the command inside one of your containers (typically named `laravel.test` but you may have changed this in your `docker-compose.yml`).

The command itself is `php vendor/bin/envoy run envoy-task`.

The format is:
`sail exec <service> <command>`

#### Simplification

If you find you need to run a lot of `envoy` commands inside `sail` and the above command is too long, you can create a `./envoy` bash script with something like this:

```
vendor/bin/sail exec laravel.test php vendor/bin/envoy run "${@:1}"
```

Then it should be as simple as running: `./envoy envoy-task` which will run `envoy-task` inside your container.